# how to union multiple sheets in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I have multiple sheets with the same structure and number of columns.
they are:

- `putri`
- `devi`
- `dewi`

I want to `UNION` them all into one sheet. I tried the following formula

`=query({putri!A2:K,devi!A2:K},"Select *")` and it shows as follow:

[image]

which i expect as follow:
[image]

how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=query(vstack(putri!A2:K,devi!A2:K,dewi!A2:K),"where Col1 is not null")
```